# actionscript 3, set color variable onClick of button

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok, the idea is simple, set of buttons on the stage, click the button change to color to draw with. I'm trying to learn flash & actionscript and not really sure where my problem is, but I can not figure out how to do this.

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Artist extends Sprite {
    public var drawing:Boolean;
    public var colorArray:Array;
    public var dc;

    public function colors() {
        colorArray = ["0xFF0000","0xFFA500","0xFFFF00","0x00FF00","0x0000FF","0x4B0082","0x8F00FF","0xFF69B4","0x00CCFF","0x008000","0x8B4513"];

        for (var i:int = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++) {
        this["btn_" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, set_color);
        }
    }

    public function set_color(e:MouseEvent):void {
        dc = colorArray;
    }

    public function Artist() {
        graphics.lineStyle(10,dc);
        drawing = false;
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrawing);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, draw);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrawing);
    }

    public function startDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void {
        graphics.moveTo( mouseX, mouseY);
        drawing = true;
    }

    public function draw(event:MouseEvent) {
        if(drawing) {
            graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
        }
    }

    public function stopDrawing(event:MouseEvent) {
        drawing = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you are close, but clicking on a button should select the color from array, right so button should store either the color or index in the color array which in the handler you will use to set "current color". in set_color handler the e.target will be the button clicked you can get index from it's name btn_1, btn_2 etc. colorArray should go outside of the colors method as eg. protected member of Artist class: `protected var colorArray:Array` and use numbers not strings for colors `0xFF0000` instead of `"0xFF0000"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the index by the button name, then you can assign the color using the clicked index.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++) {
    this["btn_" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, set_color);
}

public function set_color(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // Get the button name and fetch it's index
    var index:int = int(e.currentTarget.name.substring(4));
    dc = colorArray[index];
}
```

Also, make sure the colorArray is known throughout the whole class if you want to access it in methods.
Just define it outside the `colors` method as Lukasz said:
`protected var colorArray:Array` and use numbers not strings for colors `0xFF0000` instead of `"0xFF0000"`

Comment: You also need to init a default dc in your Artist() main function.

Comment: Gerrit, thank you, this worked, I modified it to remove the public function, and just consolidated everything inside the Artist() function. One question though perhaps you can explain the substring(4) part to me, i don't understand that bit of the code. Thanks this is working like a charm.

Comment: The `substring` part will get the button name, and extract everything from the 4th character onward (so it will extract the number in the name).

Comment: Oh yeah, and it's not a good idea to place everything inside the constructor function `Artist()`, in stead call a function `init();` from the constructor, and place the code inside that init function. Code in constructors gets compiled differently from code in other functions, you might not notice it on smaller applications, but it can make a minor difference in performance on larger applications.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tag` property on Button to put color (or color index) to button itself, then in click handler read this tag via `event.sender.tag`.
You can also generate your buttons with tags from color array (and names from another array.)